# Is Inner scroll on pop up to show history/log a bad UX practice

Tags: usability, scrolling, popup

I've to show a history/log of user actions in a pop up for that particular user along with other information. I thought of showing latest 5 actions and place a "more" button. this "more" button will increase the display space such that 10 actions can be seen and provide a scroll as well as "less" button.

I want to know is this a good/bad approach for this.

EDIT: All this should happen without effecting the pop up height.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd have all information shown on a single screen, but when that isn't possible you have to look at alternatives.  Having an inner scroll is one alternative, and given what you've explained it seems like a **rational initial choice** to me.

However, it still depends on the common case interaction; who your users are; what they are used to; etc. etc. So although it's a fair initial choice, you should do testing with your users to be sure that it's the best choice for you.

Comment: to know if it a best choice i need some other way to show them the log. can you suggest one

Comment: @strikers You already gave another way in your question.  You could use a "more" button (or even a link) which either takes the user to a full screen log view or expands the current view into an inner scroll.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all of the information in the popup window, then I can think of two options to help maximize screen real estate.

1. If there elements on the popup that need to stay persistent, then you can calculate the max-height of the modal content container based on the window height of the browser.  This way when the user "shows more" then the modal will expand down the page until the inner container reaches its max-height and a scroll bar will appear.
2. Add the overflow-y style to the parent modal container/wrapper which takes up the entire window.  The whole modal will scroll this way, but certain elements will not be persistent.

In general, I would avoid defining static heights for dynamic elements such as a modal with potentially large amounts of information.  I think you want to find ways to make use of the screen space.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of popup was to show limited information. Do not give too much information on the popup, design a separate landing page if required.I design eCommerce back offices and my client often wants me to show the activity log on the popup. Best practise is to show 5 entries then a call to action which takes user to the landing page.